# Identify PDF files which have bookmarks

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pdftk

I have a batch of pdf files (most of them are dissertations) in a directory. Some of them have bookmarks in the pdf which helps me to jump to topics easily. Now, I want to bookmark the rest of them.

In short, the question is how to identify pdf files which have bookmarks using shell or grep?

Comment: Strange, why doesn't this question satisfy the guidelines? I am not asking for a recommendation here. I am simply asking how to design a script to pick files that have embedded bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple script iterating over files in a directory may be all you need

```
for f in /Your/Directory/Path/*.pdf; 
do cpdf -list-bookmarks $f; 
done
```